# NHibernate access to hbm.xml field settings

Tags: nhibernate

I have an existing NHibernate application that was created in .NET 2, it's a WinForms app that has a separate DLL compiled for the data classes & all the hbm.xml files.

What I want to do now is show on the form which fields are not nullable, by changing the border to red.

Problem is I can't seem to find anywhere where I can cycle through the bound fields (that I can do) on the form, and read the not-null="false" (or true) parameter.

Any thoughts?

I am open to Fluent NHibernate, however this is a VB.NET app, and I am a Fluent Nhibernate noob :-)

Also open to other ways of doing this, as long as I can make them fit into the app reasonably well :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read the hbm.XML files directory as the `SessionFactory` contains `MetaData` regarding all mapped entities. One way to find all meta data for a entity is as follows;

After the SessionFactory has been built:-

```
var metaData = SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Model.Entities.Client));
for (int i = 0; i < metaData.PropertyNames.Length -1; i++)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(metaData.PropertyNames[i]);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(metaData.PropertyNullability[i].ToString());
}
```

In my case I get the following:-

```
Name
False
Address1
False
Address2
True
...
Postcode
True
```

Remember FALSE means NOT-NULL that is the property expects an entry

Another way is to add `DataAnnotations` to your model properties.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must supply a postcode")]
public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }
```

There are good articles on the internet to show you how to use this in a winforms project.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. For those that have a requirement for VB.NET, here's the equivalent:  
  
`Dim metaData As NHibernate.Metadata.IClassMetadata  
Dim tObjType As System.Type  
Dim i As Integer  
tObjType = Model.Entities.Client.GetType()  
metaData = classGlobal.tFactory.GetClassMetadata(tObjType)
For i = 0 To metaData.PropertyNames.Length
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(metaData.PropertyNames(i))  
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(metaData.PropertyNullability(i).ToString())  
Next`
Sorry about the formatting!